# Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Tags: sass

I'm getting this error even though the first argument in `map-get`, `$breakpoints`, seems to be a valid Sass map.

```
$breakpoints: (
  mobile: 320px,
  tablet: 768px,
  desktop: 992px
);

@mixin break($size) {
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $size)) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Everything seems bo be fine. Sassmeister demo - http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/351908d65048cdd21a437cdeeeaf1180
How do you compile scss code?